# How to say cut in line in British English

Tags: phrase-request, british-english

I heard in UK "queue" if more often used than "line".
Then how can I say "to cut in line" in British English?

"to cut in queue" or "to cut in line"?

I also found a expression "jump the queue", but I couldn't find out how popular the expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Jump the queue" is the usual British equivalent to "cut in line" in US English.

www.oxforddictionaries.com, an online dictionary website produced by the UK-based Oxford University Press, [defines](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cut_in_line) "cut in line" as

> *North American*
>
> Jump the queue